# Are connected, nilpotent Lie groups simply connected?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Is every connected, nilpotent Lie group over $\mathbb{C}$ simply connected? I cannot seem to find a counterexample.

Comment: There's no torsion-free example, since any nilpotent connected Lie group (real is enough) is extension of a central torus by a simply connected quotient. The only torsion-free torus is the trivial group.

Answer (score 3):

Take the torus, it is nilpotent and not simply connected.

Comment: Nonabelian examples are also possible — just factor any nilpotent Lie group by discrete subgroup of center.

Comment: And do you know any torsion-free example?

Comment: @Albi: There are no torsion-free examples.